# Нажать(утопить) кнопку при нажатии на нее Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Прошу прощения за, возможно, простой вопрос. Как зажать кнопку используя обработчик событий onclick(без использования JQuery):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="ClickFunction()">
<script>
    function ClickFunction() {
        ...
    }
</script>
```

И можно ли по нажатию кнопки подменить класс кнопки? Для примера используем Bootstrap:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="ClickFunction()">
```

По нажатию кнопки заменяем класс на `class="btn btn-info btn-lg active"`, что делает кнопку активной. Спасибо!

UPD

```html
    <script>
        function clickFunction(btn) {
            btn.classList.add("active");
        }
    </script>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="width: 19.5%" name="column" value="Today"
                           onclick="clickFunction(this)">

    <style>
        .active {
            border-style: inset;
        }
    </style>
```

Кнопка не зажимается, и "Selector active is never used"

Comment: Можно при помощи CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function ClickFunction(btn) {
  btn.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
  border-style: inset;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="ClickFunction(this)">
```

*Update*

> Кнопка не зажимается, ...

Все это (но главное - кнопка с `type="submit"`) находится внутри тега form. По нажатию кнопки вызывается функция `ClickFunction`, но сразу вслед за этим (и очень быстро) происходит отправка формы и перезагрузка страницы, которая опять приходит с сервера с ненажатой кнопкой. Если Вам это не нужно, используйте:

```
<input type="button" onclick="ClickFunction(this)" value="Submit">
```

*Update 2*

> С submit форма улетает, но не зажимается клавиша. С button форма не улетает, но клавиша зажимается.

Добавьте в кнопку атрибут `name="Submit"` и проверяйте на сервере, что элемент в данных запроса по ключу `"Submit"` равен `"Submit"`. Если это условие выполняется, выводите в кнопку атрибут `class="active"`.

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

В этом случае `onclick="ClickFunction(this)"` - не нужен.

*Update 3*

> у каждой кнопки есть name="column" и разное value, которое уже
>   хранится в сессии по ключу column="value". Нужно как-то достучаться до
>   кнопки с value="something" и добавить в нее класс active и проделывать
>   эту проверку после каждого запроса.

Перед закрывающим `</body>` выведите:

```
<script>
  var btn = document.querySelector("input[name='column'][value='something']");
  if (btn)
    btn.classList.add("active");
</script>
```

Вместо `something` выведите значение которое пришло с запросом по ключу `column`.

Comment: Почему-то не работает. Второй блок кода в head в style помещать?

Comment: @Donatello таки да, это же стиль. Обратите внимание, что @Igor добавил в функцию параметр `btn`. Возможно, Вы про это забыли

Comment: @Kir_Antipov все вроде бы один в один, добавил реальный код в вопрос после UPD.

Comment: @Donatello Ох-ох-ох. Давайте угадаю. Все это (но главное - кнопка с `type="submit"`) находится внутри тега `form`.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Да, вы правы. Кнопка указывает на раздел, по ее нажитию улетает форма и прилетает с сервера jsp страница(это мой пилотный проект Java EE на сервлетах и jsp), на которой, хотелось бы, чтобы эта самая кнопка раздела была зажата. С submit форма улетает, но не зажимается клавиша. С button форма не улетает, но клавиша зажимается.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov и style .active по-прежнему не отрабатывает, возможно потому что такой функционал предоставляет bootstrap

Comment: @Donatello Посмотрите "Update 2" в ответе.

Comment: @Igor у каждой кнопки есть name="column" и разное value, которое уже хранится в сессии по ключу column="value". Нужно как-то достучаться до кнопки с value="something" и добавить в нее класс active и проделывать эту проверку после каждого запроса. Понимаю, что я вас уже и так порядком загрузил, уж простите

Comment: @Igor Про querySelector я и не слыхал еще, но эта магия работает. Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать это без js, с помощью css псевдокласса active, т.е. даже класс у кнопки не нужно менять.

```
.class:active{
style
}
```