# Как убрать анимацию нажатия кнопки Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Кнопка реализована при помощи Bootstrap классов.

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
</form>
```

При наведении курсором она подсвечивается, при нажатии прожимается и сразу же отжимается. Данный блок кода больше ничего не делает.

Также есть скрипт, который добавляет `class active` и таким образом после нажатия делает анимацию прожатой кнопки.

В итоге при нажатии кнопка очень быстро прожимается и отжимается, а затем прожимается.

Можно ли добавить style, который уберет это мерцание(моментальное прожатие/отжатие) ?
Или уберет только отжатие, и тогда скрипт и вовсе не нужен. Спасибо.

> update привожу некий общий каркас, передающий суть задачи

```
<form method="get" action="/tasks">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="column" value="A" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="column" value="B" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="column" value="C" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
</form>

<form method="post" action="/tasks">
     <table>
          <c:forEach var="task" items="${tasks}" varStatus="status">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${status.count}</td>
                        <td>${task.content}</td>
                    </tr>
          </c:forEach>
     </table>
     <input type="submit" name="operation" value="DoSomething">
     <input type="submit" name="operation" value="DoSomethingOther">               
</form>
```

Кроме того  скрипты:

```
<script>
    var btn = document.querySelector("input[name='column'][value='${column}']");
    if (btn)
        btn.classList.add("active");
</script>

<script>
    function clickFunction(btn) {
        btn.classList.add("active");
    }
</script>
```

Есть три кнопки: A,B,C. По нажатию прилетает список tasks GET запросом. Этот список находится в form с другими кнопками для манипуляций с ней методом POST. После манипуляций при помощи sendRedirect() свою работу выполняет метод GET(column хранится в сессии, соотственно что хранится то и отрисовывает).

> update style

А также в head:

```
<style>
        .active{
            border-style: inset;
        }
</style>
```

И `.active` c пометкой `never used`. Возможно потому, что в bootstrap также есть class active который можно добавить к кнопке.

Comment: Мерцание это перезагрузка страницы при срабатывании формы?

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev я так понимаю что да. А когда страница уже прилетела отрабатывает скрипт, который прожимает кнопку.

Comment: @Donatello я же предлагал Вам создавать на сервере кнопку с классом `active` уже написанным в атрибут `class` во время обработки сабмита формы - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877794 - `Update 2`

Comment: @Donatello Если стиль `active` определен до этой кнопки, то браузер сразу отрисует ее в правильном состоянии.

Comment: @Donatello Да, и чтобы кнопка не отжималась на время ожидания ответа от сервера, надо вернуть обратно `onclick="ClickFunction()"`.

Comment: @Igor Когда я нажимаю на submit, кнопка зажимается, после этого отправляется форма и прилетает мне другая страница, где кнопка как и положено со старта не зажата. Но у нас прописан скрипт, который отрабатывает уже после и снова зажимает кнопку. Верно ли я понимаю?  Предыдущее же решение заключалось в том, чтобы по нажатию добавить класс active, но оно не спасало, потому как улетела форма и обновляла все наши старания. Теперь мы все это совместили. При нажатии добавляется класс active, форма улетает, но возвращает почему-то уже корректно прожатую кнопку. Чего я не понимаю?

Comment: @Donatello Поместите в вопрос минимум кода, который воспроизводит поведение страницы до сабмита, и минимум кода, который соответствует тому, что приходит с сервера после сабмита.

Comment: @Igor добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А где стиль `active`?

Теперь остается выяснить в какой момент Вы видите ненажатую кнопку. Из вопроса - это может быть момент, когда браузер, распарсив кусок

```
<form method="get" action="/tasks">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="column" value="A" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="column" value="B" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" name="column" value="C" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
</form>
```

отрисовывает эту часть страницы до того, как дойдет до скрипта и до стиля.

Вставьте

```
<style> 
.active { border-style: inset; }
</style>
```

в `head`, a в кнопках

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg ${ if(column == "A") { "active" } }" name="column" value="A" onclick="clickFunction(this)">
```

- не знаю как в маркапе пишется вывод чего-то в html по какому-либо условию.

*Update*

`оnclick="ClickFunction(this)"` нужен, чтобы кнопка выглядела нажатой в тот промежуток времени, пока мы отправляем форму и ждем ответа от сервера, - браузер в это время продолжает показывать старую страницу. Скрипт, добавляющий класс во время загрузки страницы, нужен, чтобы кнопка выглядела нажатой на странице, пришедшей с сервера после отправки формы, то есть на новой странице.

Comment: Стиль active пишет что не используется. Такой класс предоставляет bootstrap, возможно в этом причина. И такой код работает сейчас корректно, я просто не понимаю как clickFunction() исправляет ситуацию, если его действие обесценивает form

Comment: @Donatello Так Вас сейчас все устраивает?

Comment: да, сейчас все работает корректно. Хотелось бы понять почему. onclick не мог решить проблему, потому что form его сбрасывала. Второй скрипт не решал проблему(по нажатию зажималась кнопка, страница отрисовывалась заново с непрожатой кнопкой, а потом он выполнялся и прожимал клавишу). А к нему добавили onclick(который как мы помним не мог ничего поделать из-за нахождения в form) и тут все заработало. Как?

Comment: @Donatello `оnclick="ClickFunction(this)"` нужен, чтобы кнопка выглядела нажатой в тот промежуток времени, пока мы отправляем форму и ждем ответа от сервера, - браузер в это время продолжает показывать старую страницу. Скрипт, добавляющий класс во время загрузки страницы, нужен, чтобы кнопка выглядела нажатой на странице, пришедшей с сервера после отправки формы, то есть на новой странице.

Comment: Т.е. скрипт где нужно было зажать кнопку на странице, которую вернул сервер выполнится до ее отрисовки?

Comment: @Donatello Это зависит от конкретного браузера.

Comment: Когда добавили скрипт зажатия кнопки на странице которая прилетает с сервера было следующее: кнопка зажималась и отжималась, а потом зажималась. Тогда вывод такой: зажималась и отжималась она по клику на нее еще до отправки формы? Иначе onclick не понадобился бы.

Comment: @Donatello Да, на старой странице.

Comment: А можно как-нибудь узнать - выполняется какой-то конкретный скрипт до отрисовки страницы или в процессе?

Comment: В Developer Tools, возможно есть что-то для этого.

Comment: Поэтому я и предлагаю добавлять этот класс тегу кнопки на сервере - чтобы у браузера не было вариантов.

Comment: Просто изначально создал вопрос из-за такой идеи(возможно было бы проще, если это возможно): раз по нажатию кнопка зажимается и отжимается, не было бы лучше запретить ей отжиматься? Как нибудь в стиле прописать это. И тогда не нужен onClick()

Comment: Спасибо вам еще раз